# Heating and cooling for insulated shed

Tags: heating, air-conditioning

I have a 120 sq. Foot shed. That I’d like to insulate and put climate control in.

The walls are full height, and it would have an attic area after insulation/drywall installation with the 30 degree roof trusses. So I have some height.

The floor is insulated and sits on top of a concrete pad.

Problem is, this is even smaller than a tiny house… which usually considers a mini split system for 500-1000 sq. Feet.

I’d love an in-wall a/c with heat, but they are all massively more powerful than I’d really need.

Basically I’d like an efficient way to keep the insulated/drywalled shed above freezing in the winter for paint  and similar items, and below 70 or 80 degrees when its really hot out. I might also want to be able to work in there so being able to change a setting and keep a nice 65 F would be cool. But generally the less power the better, with a regular range of 35 - 75 F.

Thanks for any suggestions!

The best answers will address efficiency and cost (up front, running and maintenance) in mind.

Thanks for any ideas / suggestions.

Comment: Similar problem, my local A/C guy is telling me I need a gas furnace with ducts, and a traditional 13 SEER A/C on a pad, and I'm thinking "yeah... and an El Camino, and a Mullet, and some Skynyrd on 8-track".  What's the coldest temperature you need the heat to work at?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a homebrewer and we use simple dual-phase temperature controllers for things like this, usually it's temp control for small chambers like a chest freezer rather than a whole shed (which means built-in cooling, and we just have to worry about a space heater for cold seasons.

If I were in your position, I'd probably mount a window AC in the wall and use a small (~300W maybe) space heater, with both hooked up to the same temp controller I already have and use (Inkbird ITC-308) set to the preferred temperature limits.

Comment: How about a window heat pump?

Comment: I guess I could clarify... I already have a window AC unit and a small space heater that I use, also they're probably significantly cheaper than a window heat pump. Small sqft heat pump unit would be ideal if cost and footprint were comparable.

Comment: Well, space heaters are infamous for being cheaper **to buy**, but certainly the most expensive possible heater **to operate**.  That needs to go into the heat-pump calculation.

Comment: y'all are talking about exactly what I'm  confused about. A heat pump doesn't exist for small square footages (100-120 sq. ft), so It'd be way overkill on cost and install time. Even window units (heat + A/C) are for larger square footages - and I don't know if you can set them to a range rather than a single temp. If @FredricShope has discovered this same problem... then a space heater seems like it will fit the bill. Certainly you'll pay less with a space heater set to 35 degrees all the time than you'd pay with a dual-a/c-heat window unit set to a single temp (50 - 60 degress).

Comment: @TheJeff If you look at that temp controller I mentioned, it has low/high temps and adjustable offset (number of degrees above/below it ignores so it's not running either AC or heater constantly. There are a lot of other temp controller models that do this too, and I'm not affiliated with Inkbird I just like using it (I have two)

Comment: @TheJeff -- have you looked at window/TTW heat pump units?

Answer (score 2):

Several years ago I built a shed about twice the size of yours (11x25 feet) and used the opportunity to experiment with heavy insulation and passive solar design. The concrete slab sat on 1" of EPS foam board, the walls were 2x4 at 16" centers with R13 fiberglass batts, the outdoor cladding was 1" polyiso foam board covered with acrylic stucco, and I built raised-heel trusses so that I could have something like R60 blown fiberglass insulation near-full-depth all the way to the edge of the walls (IIRC it was about 16" deep in the middle and 11" deep at the edges). The interior was finished with 1/2" drywall. There was also a small basement/cellar the full 11 foot depth of the building by about 7 feet long.

The building was oriented on an east-west axis so one long side faced south. It had ordinary insulated steel doors on the north and east faces; on the south face there were three double-pane vinyl windows with a total of about 42 square feet of glass. I sized the tails of the roof trusses and the vertical position of the windows so that the roof overhang would shade the windows during the peak of the summer while allowing sunlight to shine into the windows during the winter.

With all that said: most years I worried about it freezing for only one week in the winter. We're a heating-dominant climate; outdoor temperatures in the teens (Fahrenheit) are common in the coldest part of winter. The only reason I worried about freezing during that week is that we routinely get temperature inversions; these cause heavy clouds to form and severely reduce the amount of solar insolation through those windows. I'd run a little space heater during those times. Apart from this condition it was always at least 35 degrees and often warmer in there all through the winter with no supplemental heat.

In the summer time it got warm in there -- mid 80's, probably, while daytime outdoor temperatures had overnight lows mid- to upper-60's and daytime highs mid-90's or even a hair over 100. Again, that was with no supplemental cooling. It probably would have done better if I'd at least opened the windows at night.

Your shed is already built so it's too late to do raised heel trusses and maybe too late to do outdoor insulation. Is it possible to add a south-facing window and a roof overhang or awning to shade it from the summer sun? The solar heat is a big deal come winter.

If you insulate the wall cavities *and add even 1/2" of foam board sheets covering the wall studs, just like the drywall does* I imagine that would be a big help in reducing thermal bridging. Dealing with heat loss at the wall-roof junction will be hard, and the attic isn't very tall, so roof/attic insulation is tough. Foam board insulates better than fiberglass does; maybe before ceiling drywall is installed you can cut pieces of foam and fit them between the trusses so there is 3-5 inches total thickness of foam.

Comment: Wow what a project. Thanks for sharing. Mine is in CO, so extreme heat, extreme cold, hail, and all sorts of weather are possible. There are no windows, I figure there might be 2' batts for the ceiling hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

A room size AC will work just fine , such as 8000 BTU. I have a hobby room , 150 sq ft.) ; standard 2X4 framing , fiber glas in walls and ceiling. I set the temperature for 80 F. I am seldom in the room but it has aquariums that I do not want to get too hot. The AC works fine  ( 15 years). I can't understand why you think there would be a problem. A few hundred watts of aquarium heaters keep it warm in winter. I did put spring hinges on both doors as my wife for gets to close doors,

Answer (score 0):

Build the wall with 2x6's and insulate with Rockwool. Use 2 layers or 1.5 inches of polyisocyanate in 2 layers staggered.